# Extjs - why is the child node not removed from the parent node when the child node has been removed from tree store?

Tags: javascript, extjs

working with extjs version 5 - Ext.data.TreeStore

```
getGrid().getStore().remove(record); //web page shows that this record has been removed

parentNode = getGrid().getStore().getById(record.parentNode.id);

console.log(parentNode.childNodes); //why is the record removed still one of the child nodes?
```

My goal is to determine if the parent node still has any child nodes, if no more child nodes, then remove the parent node.
But since the parent node still has references to the child node even after the child node has been removed, I can't achieve my goal.
Thanks

Comment: Could you create an example on https://fiddle.sencha.com/

Comment: @user2760273 In that case, you need to check your parentNode.children instead of parentNode.childNodes. check parentNode children from Store data.

Comment: @ajay thakur - I don't see children as a property of parentNode https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/guides/components/trees.html#components-_-trees_-_the_node_interface